# Execute python commands with a python interpreter inside a docker container

Tags: python, docker

I have created the following Dockerfile, which I named `python.Dockerfile`

```
# Stage 1: Set up Python environment
FROM python:3.9-slim as python-env

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install requests

# Stage 2: Final stage to create the container
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Python environment from the first stage
COPY --from=python-env / /

# Expose any necessary ports (if needed)
EXPOSE 8000

# Command to run Python interpreter
CMD ["python"]
```

After I build the container using `docker build -t py_interpret -f docker/python.Dockerfile`, I am able to run a container for this image in an interactive, detached mode using `docker run -it -d py_interpret`.

**My question is**: *I would like to be able to execute python commands using the python interpreter within this docker container programmatically.*

On the command line, I know I can do this by attaching to the container (via a `docker attach py_interpret`), which puts me inside the running Python interpreter within the container.

I want to be able to do something like this, but 1. without having to attach to the container and 2. use the Python docker SDK to do this. For example...

*example.py*

```py
# Start detached, interactive docker container
container = client.containers.run(
    'intercode-python',
    command='python',
    tty=True,
    stdin_open=True,
    detach=True,
)

# Send a python command to the container
command = "print('Hello World')"
response = container.exec_run(command)

# Get the output of the command
output = response.output.decode('utf-8')
print(output)
```

However, the above does not work. (I think) `command` is being treated as a bash command rather than being fed in as standard input to be run with the python interpreter.

I have tried `docker exec <container name> <python command>`, but this does not seem to actually execute `<python command>` with the interpreter (I get a `OCI runtime exec failed` error, presumably because `<python command>` is being run on the command line, instead of with the python interpreter)

Comment: `container = client.containers.run` eh? You should be able to get `stdout` without any library?

Comment: Shut my mouth, you're running it different to what I had to do in the past. However, `stdout` might help search

Comment: What does the documentation say that `exec_run` does?

Comment: @UpAndAdam according to the [docs](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.exec_run), "Run a command inside this container. Similar to docker exec". Not very informative. The reason I think it's being treated as a bash command is because when I run it as "docker exec  py_interpret python -c 'a=4'", it works. However, this doesn't meet my needs because a=4 is not remembered.

Comment: @roganjosh Sorry, I didn't quite understand. I don't think the container object has a `run` function according to the [docs](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container)? `exec_run` is the closest to running a command.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with the second Python interpreter?  How would you do it without Docker?  What you're proposing seems most similar to opening two terminal windows, running `python` in one of them, and then trying to send data to its REPL from the other process, but that would be a pretty unusual setup IME.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yeah what you mentioned is the right idea. I basically want to use the Python interpreter as an execution sandbox for trying out dynamically generated Python code. In addition, rather than simply saving the generated code to a file and executing "python <file.py>" in a docker container, it's important for my use case that the mode of execution is closer to a python interpreter / jupyter notebook style, rather than running a python file.